# Bash - seleccion de líneas por valor sin usar grep, awk o sed

Tags: bash

estoy trabajando con un archivo CSV que se ve de la siguiente forma:

```
V1,"V2","V3","V4","V5","V6","V7","V8","V9","V10","Class"
65,Female,0.7,0.1,187,16,18,6.8,3.3,0.9,1
62,Male,10.9,5.5,699,64,100,7.5,3.2,0.74,1
62,Male,7.3,4.1,490,60,68,7,3.3,0.89,1
```

Solo me interesan las columnas V1, V2, V8 y V9.
Quiero hacer lo siguiente:

- seleccionar las columnas V1, V2, V8 y V9
- ordenar según V2
- seleccionar aquellas filas en las que el valor de V8 sea 3

Hasta ahora sólo he conseguido hacer los 2 primeros pasos:

```
sort -t',' -k 2 phpOJxGL9.csv| cut -d',' -f1,2,8,9
```

Cómo puedo indicar el valor para la columna **sin usar grep, sed** o **awk**?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿por qué no puedes usar las herramientas que realmente son adecuadas para esta tarea? Sin grep, sed o awk, la cosa se puede hacer (por ejemplo con Bash puro) pero es como ir a buscar setas con un helicóptero

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar', estoy haciendo un ejercicio y así lo indican. Otra opción sería pasar el csv a json y con jq hacer la selección de líneas?

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar', Lo he pasado a JSON finalmente y la selección sigue fallándome igualmente. Esta es la consulta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/491170/232968?sem=2