# Bash - selección de líneas por valor con jq

Tags: bash, jq

estoy trabajando con un archivo CSV que se ve de la siguiente forma:

```
V1,"V2","V3","V4","V5","V6","V7","V8","V9","V10","Class"
65,Female,0.7,0.1,187,16,18,6.8,3.3,0.9,1
62,Male,10.9,5.5,699,64,100,7.5,3.2,0.74,1
62,Male,7.3,4.1,490,60,68,7,3.3,0.89,1
58,Male,1,0.4,182,14,20,6.8,3.4,1,1
72,Male,3.9,2,195,27,59,7.3,2.4,0.4,1
46,Male,1.8,0.7,208,19,14,7.6,4.4,1.3,1
26,Female,0.9,0.2,154,16,12,7,3.5,1,1
29,Female,0.9,0.3,202,14,11,6.7,3.6,1.1,1
17,Male,0.9,0.3,202,22,19,7.4,4.1,1.2,2
55,Male,0.7,0.2,290,53,58,6.8,3.4,1,1
57,Male,0.6,0.1,210,51,59,5.9,2.7,0.8,1
72,Male,2.7,1.3,260,31,56,7.4,3,0.6,1
64,Male,0.9,0.3,310,61,58,7,3.4,0.9,2
74,Female,1.1,0.4,214,22,30,8.1,4.1,1,1
61,Male,0.7,0.2,145,53,41,5.8,2.7,0.87,1
25,Male,0.6,0.1,183,91,53,5.5,2.3,0.7,2
38,Male,1.8,0.8,342,168,441,7.6,4.4,1.3,1
33,Male,1.6,0.5,165,15,23,7.3,3.5,0.92,2
40,Female,0.9,0.3,293,232,245,6.8,3.1,0.8,1
40,Female,0.9,0.3,293,232,245,6.8,3.1,0.8,1
51,Male,2.2,1,610,17,28,7.3,2.6,0.55,1
51,Male,2.9,1.3,482,22,34,7,2.4,0.5,1
62,Male,6.8,3,542,116,66,6.4,3.1,0.9,1
40,Male,1.9,1,231,16,55,4.3,1.6,0.6,1
```

Lo he convertido a JSON con el fin de hacer lo siguiente:

- seleccionar las columnas V1, V2, V8 y V9
- ordenar según V2
- seleccionar aquellas filas en las que el valor de V8 sea 3

El JSON se ve así:

```
[
  {
    "V1": 65,
    "V2": "Female",
    "V3": 0.7,
    "V4": 0.1,
    "V5": 187,
    "V6": 16,
    "V7": 18,
    "V8": 6.8,
    "V9": 3.3,
    "V10": 0.9,
    "Class": 1
  },
  {
    "V1": 62,
    "V2": "Male",
    "V3": 10.9,
    "V4": 5.5,
    "V5": 699,
    "V6": 64,
    "V7": 100,
    "V8": 7.5,
    "V9": 3.2,
    "V10": 0.74,
    "Class": 1
  },
  {
    "V1": 62,
    "V2": "Male",
    "V3": 7.3,
    "V4": 4.1,
    "V5": 490,
    "V6": 60,
    "V7": 68,
    "V8": 7,
    "V9": 3.3,
    "V10": 0.89,
    "Class": 1
  },
  {
    "V1": 58,
    "V2": "Male",
    "V3": 1,
    "V4": 0.4,
    "V5": 182,
    "V6": 14,
    "V7": 20,
    "V8": 6.8,
    "V9": 3.4,
    "V10": 1,
    "Class": 1
  },
```

Hasta ahora he conseguido hacer esto:

```
curl -s "csvjson.json" | jq '.V1, .V2, .V8, .V9' | jq -s -c 'sort_by(.V2) | .[]' | jq -c 'to_entries[] | select(.value.V8 =="3")
```

No obtengo ningún resultado y debo cortar (Ctrl + C) la ejecución.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si omito `| jq -c 'to_entries[] | select(.value.V8 =="3")` no obtengo ningún fallo pero tampoco respuesta.

Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: creo que convertirlo a JSON no es buena idea ya que te va a generar un objeto por cada fila y no por columnas...

Comment: ¿Quieres hacer las tres cosas a la vez o una cada vez?

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent, el cambio a JSON lo muestro en la consulta. La decisión de hacerlo así es porque debo obtener este filtrado sin poder usar grep, awk o sed

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar', lo hago por pasos porque me resulta más fácil de entender. Soy muy nuevo con el scripting y quiero ir usando pipes para aprender paso a paso la verdad

Comment: ¿y te funciona cada uno de los pasos dados hasta ahora?

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar', pues la verdad es que no lo sé porque no me salta error de ningún tipo pero tampoco me sale nada por pantalla. En algún caso me sale la opción de escribir más línea de código como si lo hubiera guardado en una variable y en otros casos se queda colgado y debo hacer 'Ctrl+C'

Comment: sería bueno que le dieras a [edit] y dar un [mcve]. Por ejemplo, mencionas `to_entries` en tu código y no veo nada así en los datos

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar', perdona, no estoy seguro de haberte entendido bien. Sí que menciono que al quitar ```to_entries``` no obtengo respuesta. Dices que debería añadir cómo queda la consola al ejecutar el código?

Comment: por eso digo que iría bien tener un ejemplo completo para poder replicar

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar', no tengo muy claro cómo dejar el CSV para leerlo por todos. Con google Drive no creo que sea posible. Y poner el listado completo igual es mucho texto. Se me ocurre indicar en el archivo inicial, algunas líneas más del CSV

Comment: exacto, un [mcve] vendría a ser unas cuantas líneas completas de CSV junto con su equivalente exacto en JSON, sin cosas cortadas

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar', ya he ampliado tanto la info del CSV como la del JSON. A ver si así es más claro. Gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: ya veo. El tema es que ni siquiera el primer comando es correcto. Para imprimir el campo V1 solamente, por ejemplo, debes decir `jq '.[] | .V1'`.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar', tras mirar y mirar, tengo esto ```cat csvjson.json | jq -c '.[] | jq .V1, .V2, .V8, .V9 | select(.V8 =="3") | select(.V2 =="Male")' ```, pero me da ```error cerca de '('```

Comment: si usas `.V1, .V2, .V8, .V9` ya no puedes hacer el `select()` pues no tiene manera de ver cuál es el campo. `jq '.[] | select (.V8 == 7)' fichero.json` sí funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Aqui lo tienes ( le puse .V8==7 para que muestre algo, tú cambia a 3 ):

```
$ jq 'map({V1,V2,V8,V9})|sort_by(.V2)|map(select(.V8==7))' csvjson.json

[
  {
    "V1": 62,
    "V2": "Male",
    "V8": 7,
    "V9": 3.3
  }
]
```

---

Te muestro paso por paso, como es que el pipe "|" nos ayuda, en 3 pasos:

Primero: El comando "map" itera sobre cada elemento del arreglo (lo que pongas dentro del parentesis lo aplica a cada elemento); al poner los campos que te interesan dentro de las llaves permine visualizar sólo los campos que te interesan:

```
$ jq 'map({V1,V2,V8,V9})'  csvjson.json
[
  {
    "V1": 65,
    "V2": "Female",
    "V8": 6.8,
    "V9": 3.3
  },
  {
    "V1": 62,
    "V2": "Male",
    "V8": 7.5,
    "V9": 3.2
  },
  {
    "V1": 62,
    "V2": "Male",
    "V8": 7,
    "V9": 3.3
  },
  {
    "V1": 58,
    "V2": "Male",
    "V8": 6.8,
    "V9": 3.4
  }
]
```

Segundo: Luego, a ese resultado obtenido (un arreglo de objetos) lo ordenamos por el campo V2, con el comando sort_by(.V2):

```
$ jq 'map({V1,V2,V8,V9})|sort_by(.V2)' csvjson.json
[
  {
    "V1": 65,
    "V2": "Female",
    "V8": 6.8,
    "V9": 3.3
  },
  {
    "V1": 62,
    "V2": "Male",
    "V8": 7.5,
    "V9": 3.2
  },
  {
    "V1": 62,
    "V2": "Male",
    "V8": 7,
    "V9": 3.3
  },
  {
    "V1": 58,
    "V2": "Male",
    "V8": 6.8,
    "V9": 3.4
  }
]
```

Por último, volemos a usar nuestra comando "map" para iterar sobre cada uno de los objetos del arreglo y a cada elemento le aplicamos un filtro con el comando "select", donde a cada objeto se le aplica la regla ".V8==7" :

```
$ jq 'map({V1,V2,V8,V9})|sort_by(.V2)|map(select(.V8==7))' csvjson.json

[
  {
    "V1": 62,
    "V2": "Male",
    "V8": 7,
    "V9": 3.3
  }
]
```

Espero sea de utilidad la explicación.

Tambien jq funciona en el shell Windows (cmd), si te interesa, puedes preguntarme.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: También jq funciona en el shell de Windows (cmd), si a alguien le interesa puede preguntar.

Answer (score 0):

Invirtiendo el orden de las tareas es una forma

- seleccionar aquellas filas en las que el valor de V8 sea 3
- ordenar según V2
- seleccionar las columnas V1, V2, V8 y V9

queda algo así:

```
$ jq  '[ .[] | select(.V8==3) ]| sort_by(.V2) | .[] | .V1, .V2, .V8, .V9' csvjson.json
```

en partes:

- seleccionar aquellas filas en las que el valor de V8 sea 3

`[ .[] | select(.V8==3) ]`

*del array `.[]` seleccionar elementos donde `v8 == 3`y con esto armar un array ( los corchetes exteriores )*

- ordenar según V2

`sort_by(.V2)`

- seleccionar las columnas V1, V2, V8 y V9

`.[] | .V1, .V2, .V8, .V9`

*Crear un Array y luego filtrar `.V1, .V2, .V8, .V9`*

Para formatear la salida o definir varables para script hay varias opciones:

```
$ jq -r --arg v_ocho 3 '[ .[] | select(.V8==($v_ocho|tonumber)) ]| sort_by(.V2) | .[] | [.V1, .V2, .V8, .V9] | @csv' csvjson.json
```

Notas:

- `-r` es salida raw ( evita escapear las cosas )
- `--arg v_ocho 3` define una variable/argumento para el `V8`
- `($v_ocho|tonumber)` se asegura que la comparación sea numérica
- corchetes alrededor del último filtro y `| @csv` imprime las líneas en formato csv

Answer (score 0):

Considera usar [Miller](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) y operar directamente sobre el CSV:

```bash
$ mlr --csv cut -f V1,V2,V8,V9 then sort -f V2 then filter '$V8=3' file.csv
V1,V2,V8,V9
65,Female,3,3.3
26,Female,3,3.5
29,Female,3,3.6
74,Female,3,4.1
40,Female,3,3.1
40,Female,3,3.1
62,Male,3,3.2
62,Male,3,3.3
58,Male,3,3.4
72,Male,3,2.4
46,Male,3,4.4
17,Male,3,4.1
55,Male,3,3.4
57,Male,3,2.7
72,Male,3,3
64,Male,3,3.4
61,Male,3,2.7
25,Male,3,2.3
38,Male,3,4.4
33,Male,3,3.5
51,Male,3,2.6
51,Male,3,2.4
62,Male,3,3.1
40,Male,3,1.6
```

Si necesitas salida en formato *JSON* usa:

```bash
$ mlr -i csv -o json cut -f V1,V2,V8,V9 then sort -f V2 then filter '$V8=3' file.csv
[
{
  "V1": 65,
  "V2": "Female",
  "V8": 3,
  "V9": 3.3
},
{
  "V1": 26,
  "V2": "Female",
  "V8": 3,
  "V9": 3.5
},
{
  "V1": 29,
  "V2": "Female",
  "V8": 3,
  "V9": 3.6
},
{
  "V1": 74,
  "V2": "Female",
  "V8": 3,
  "V9": 4.1
},
{
  "V1": 40,
  "V2": "Female",
  "V8": 3,
  "V9": 3.1
},
{
  "V1": 40,
  "V2": "Female",
  "V8": 3,
  "V9": 3.1
},
{
  "V1": 62,
  "V2": "Male",
  "V8": 3,
  "V9": 3.2
},
{
  "V1": 62,
  "V2": "Male",
  "V8": 3,
  "V9": 3.3
},
{
  "V1": 58,
  "V2": "Male",
  "V8": 3,
  "V9": 3.4
},
{
  "V1": 72,
  "V2": "Male",
  "V8": 3,
  "V9": 2.4
},
{
  "V1": 46,
  "V2": "Male",
  "V8": 3,
  "V9": 4.4
},
{
  "V1": 17,
  "V2": "Male",
  "V8": 3,
  "V9": 4.1
},
{
  "V1": 55,
  "V2": "Male",
  "V8": 3,
  "V9": 3.4
},
{
  "V1": 57,
  "V2": "Male",
  "V8": 3,
  "V9": 2.7
},
{
  "V1": 72,
  "V2": "Male",
  "V8": 3,
  "V9": 3
},
{
  "V1": 64,
  "V2": "Male",
  "V8": 3,
  "V9": 3.4
},
{
  "V1": 61,
  "V2": "Male",
  "V8": 3,
  "V9": 2.7
},
{
  "V1": 25,
  "V2": "Male",
  "V8": 3,
  "V9": 2.3
},
{
  "V1": 38,
  "V2": "Male",
  "V8": 3,
  "V9": 4.4
},
{
  "V1": 33,
  "V2": "Male",
  "V8": 3,
  "V9": 3.5
},
{
  "V1": 51,
  "V2": "Male",
  "V8": 3,
  "V9": 2.6
},
{
  "V1": 51,
  "V2": "Male",
  "V8": 3,
  "V9": 2.4
},
{
  "V1": 62,
  "V2": "Male",
  "V8": 3,
  "V9": 3.1
},
{
  "V1": 40,
  "V2": "Male",
  "V8": 3,
  "V9": 1.6
}
]
```

Miller es como `awk`, `sed`, `cut`, `join` y `sort` para formatos de datos como *CSV*, *TSV* y *JSON*. Consulta su [excelente documentación](https://miller.readthedocs.io/).